# How can I validate the dependency of existance of value for one property value based on the existance of another property value in JSON schema

Tags: java, json, schema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
"name": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
"credit_card": { 
     "type": ["string", "null"]
},
"billing_address": {
     "type": ["string", "null"]
}
},

"dependencies": [{
"credit_card": ["billing_address"]
}]

}
```

I want the billing_address value to be present if the credit_card value is provided. But since I have specified the type of billing_address as null it accepts null value even when the credit_card value is present and hence not validating. Could someone suggest the right approach for doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dependencies` should be defined as an object `{}` not an array `[]`. You just need to remove the outer square brackets:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "credit_card": ["billing_address"]
}
```

Overall, this gives the following schema:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "credit_card": {
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "billing_address": {
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "credit_card": ["billing_address"]
    }
}
```

Using the above schema, the following JSON is valid:

```json
{
  "name": "Abel",
  "credit_card": "1234...",
  "billing_address": "some address here..."
}
```

But the following JSON is *invalid*:

```json
{
  "name": "Abel",
  "credit_card": "1234"
}
```

You can test these using an online validator such as [this one](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/).

---

You may also want to consider removing the `null` values you are using in the schema. For example, by using this:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "credit_card": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "billing_address": {
            "type": "string",
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "credit_card": ["billing_address"]
    }
}
```

Using this revised schema, you will now also get a validation error for JSON such as the following:

```json
{
  "name": "Abel",
  "credit_card": null,
  "billing_address": "some address here..."
}
```

---

**Update** - both fields are present but null:

If both `credit_card` and `billing_address` are null, then this case can be handled using a conditional validation (added to the end of our schema below):

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "credit_card": {
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "billing_address": {
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "credit_card": ["billing_address"]
    },
    "if": {
      "properties": { "credit_card": { "const": null } }
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": { "billing_address": { "const": null } }
    }
}
```

Now, the following will also be valid:

```json
{
  "name": "Abel",
  "credit_card": null,
  "billing_address": null
}
```

One note of warning: This uses a relatively newer feature of the JSON Schema spec. It is supported by the online validator I referred to above - but I do not know if it is supported by whatever validator you may be using.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But doing so does not help me when both the field are null. I want my schema to be considered valid when both the fields are null. @andrewjames

Comment: Updated to handle the case when both fields are present, but null.

Comment: I think the issue lies in the support for JSON version. I am using mule 4 and I am adding the dependencies inside if then else. I think if then else is a JSON 7 feature and mule does not support that. @andrewjames are you aware of anything that can be use as an alternative of if then else in JSON 04?

Comment: I have used fixed the issue by using oneOf which is support in JSON draft 04 as an alternative to if else then. It works successfully. :)

Comment: Glad you have a solution that works for you. You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so other people can see exactly how you solved the problem using your approach.